# My stack has no "top" attribute for some reason

Tags: python, stack

```
import random

value = {
    "Two":2,"Three":3, "Four":4,
    "Five":5, "Six":6, "Seven":7,
    "Eight":8, "Nine":9, "Ten":10,
    "Jack":10, "Queen":10, "King":10,
    "Ace":10
}

suit = {
    "H":"Hearts","C":"Clubs",
    "S":"Spades","D":"Diamonds",
}

def getList(value):
    return list(value.keys())
def getList(suit):
    return list(suit.keys())

listValue = getList(value)
print(list)
listSuit = getList(suit)

deck = []
for s in listSuit:
    for v in listValue:
        deck.append((value[v], suit[s]))
random.shuffle(deck)
print(deck)

state = 'Y'
score = 0
print('Please answer with Y(yes) or N(no)!')

while (state == 'Y'):
    print('Draw a card? (Y/N)')
    state = input()
    if (state == "Y"):
        score += deck.top()
        print(deck.pop())
        print(score)
```

I don't know why, but it all works well up to that point — where I want to calculate the score using `.top()` — and just gets the error message

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'top'
```

It works with `.pop()` so I'm just confused.

Comment: Did you intend to define `getList` twice? The first function definition is lost when you do that. What do you think `list.top()` does?

Comment: `list` is not a stack; things other than stacks can have a `pop` method.  Didn't the absence of `push` tip you off?  You don't seem confused about using `append`, which is not a stack operation.

Comment: Interestingly, both versions of `getList` are functionally equivalent, so you didn't break anything per se by redefining it, just caused yourself some extra keyboard clicky-clacking. Also, what is `print(list)` meant to do?

Comment: See [Using lists as stacks](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks) in the python documentation for specific description on how to _treat_ a list as a stack, and note the lack of a `top` method

Comment: `deck` is a list which *do* have a `pop()` method, you're just (unsuccessfully) using it as though it was a stack. Ask yourself what would be the Python equivalent of what a stack `top()` method does (i.e. what list position would that always be?)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to get the first element in `deck`, add it to `score`, and then remove it from `deck`.

You will achieve this with the following code:

```
top_card = deck.pop(0) # return the first element in your list object and remove it from the object
score += top_card
```